# Passing an array into a handlebars partial to create a list

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm trying to pass an array into a handlebars partial to create an unordered list within the template.

Here's the syntax I was hoping would work.

```
{{> message
    title="This is a title"
    bullet="{'Item 1','Item 2','Item 3'}"
    button="View"
}}
```

I was then hoping that looping through the array would output each item as a list item

```
{{#each bullet}}
    <li>{{ this }}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Unfortunately that didn't work and an empty list was output.

To get around this I've used the ParseJSON block helper which does work but doesn't seem like the correct way to go about things.

```
{{#parseJSON '{"list":["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"]}'}}
    {{> message
        title="This is a title"
        button="View"
    }}
{{/parseJSON}}
```

Does anyone know a better way of getting around my issue please?

Comment: The value you are using in the each should be assigned an array. You do not need to use json.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should work like this:

```
{{> message {title: "This is a title", bullet: ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3'], button: "View"} }}
```

Now the second parameter (`{title: ... }`) is the context of the message template. Inside the message template you can use the bullet array for your each loop:

```
{{#each bullet}}
    <li>{{ this }}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This solution throws a Parse Error.